# Is it possible to wrap a custom directive within a form and have Angular evaluates its validity?

Tags: angularjs

In my app there is a screen with a tab set where each tab is rendered with a directive, and there is a form split between some of these tabs with ng-form. When a button is clicked, I check if any sub form is valid or not like this:

```
function checkFormValidity(form) { //Form is an Angular form object
      var subForms = getSubForms(); //Get an array with the names of the sub forms
      for(var i = 0; i < subForms.length; i++) {
        var subform = subForms[i];
        if(form[subform].$invalid) {
          //Flash error messages
        }
     }
}
```

So far the only restrictions in the sub forms were some required fields, and with ng-required attribute Angular takes care of setting each subform as valid or not. Easy!

Now I have to add a new restriction in order to perform the action. However it is not related to user's input in the UX but to the state of an object in an array of objects.

In one of the tabs I'm already displaying that collection of objects and hence have access to its states to perform the checking. So I was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
<div ng-form="newSubForm">
    <list-items><list-items>
 </div>
```

And have Angular setting `newSubForm` as valid or not based on this custom checking I need to do. So something similar as the ng-required for inputs fields.

I would like to avoid to manually trigger custom checkings so I don't touch checkFormValidity method. It would look ugly to run custom checking after the for loop.

Thanks for your help

Comment: ui-validate might get you most of the way there.